# Unable to install LIbraries for Python3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.5

I had pyhton2.7 and Python3.5 in my laptop but to use f string, I installed  pyhton3.6.5 and removed python3.5. Now I have python2.7 and Python3.6.5. But I am not able to install any libraries for the python3.6.5

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054281/pip-for-python3-6-5-on-debian9-4) but it doesn't works

Please let me know how can I install modules for the python3.6.5

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install foo`

Comment: Instead of your link, try this [Two versions of python on linux. how to make x.x the default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256389/7414759)

Comment: A possible scenario is that you're installing libraries correctly. But, you're opening the wrong python environment ([_See this_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045752/module-installs-but-cannot-be-imported/48045822#48045822))

Comment: i tried this but its gives an error python3 command not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install [Package_to_install]
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the installation in your system, if there are several python3 installs in your system it might be an issue.

Either uninstall the other version of python3 or create a virtual environment and then install the library.

Check the description at https://www.alexkras.com/how-to-use-virtualenv-in-python-to-install-packages-locally/